# d3 extent function with dates using dc.js and crossfilter produces differing results

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm fairly new to D3 and have created a few charts with varying degrees of success, but I'm now stuck on an issue that doesn't make sense to me when using the extent to define the domain in a dc.js barChart chart type.

Using the following produces strange results with the x axis between 0 and 2000'ish:

```
.x(d3.time.scale().range([0, width]).domain(d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.dt; })))
```

while the following, with exactly the same values hardcoded in the scale ranges, works perfectly.

```
.x(d3.time.scale().range([0, width]).domain([parseFormat("2014-03-28"),parseFormat("2015-08-07")]))
```

As far as I can see there is no difference between the array that is passed to the domain function, but I get two different results.  What am I missing?

```
var test = d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d.dt; });
var test2 = [parseFormat("2014-03-28"),parseFormat("2015-08-07")];
debugger;

> test
< Array (2) = $1
0Fri Mar 28 0014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
1Fri Aug 07 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)

> test2
< Array (2) = $2
0Fri Mar 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
1Fri Aug 07 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Comment: I'm deleting my answer because it's getting a lot of hate - I guess I should have just commented and not answered. The first data shows year `0014`; @user5072412 said it was a substring index error.

Comment: Where was the hate?  Did I miss something?

Comment: Folks didn't like my short answer (multiple downvotes) so I wrote a comment and deleted my answer. It's sad that there are so many angry people on this platform when it's supposed to be about helping people.

Comment: It is, isn't it? :-(

Comment: Well, your comment helped me :-)